# collect user feedback via Firebase Analytics?

Tags: firebase, reporting, firebase-analytics

I want my app to provide users a way to send a feedback, feature request or malfunction report. I thought this would be a great use case for Firebase Analytics custom events. However, it seems like there is no way to show individual custom events with all data in Firebase console. Is Analytics meant to collect only *statistical* data or am I missing something?

Comment: You might want to remove the "what should I use instead?", since: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Analytics is primarily only concerned about statistical data, but there is little stopping you from putting whatever you want in your custom events.

Just know that if you want to get a hold of attributes from custom analytics events, you will need to [export your data to BigQuery](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765?hl=en).

Firebase doesn't have a formal mechanism for gathering end user feedback, but you are always free to [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) for anything you would like to see.

Comment: I've submitted the feature request. Thank you, your response was (as always) on point. I think I'll stick to firebase database as of now, but I hope to see a dedicated tool for that.

Comment: Don't forget that event param values have a 100 character max so you might have to break the feedback up into multiple params